# Oracle connection string with at sign @ in pasword

Tags: python, django, oracle, connection-string, django-oracle

I have a code that connect to oracle using connection string:

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('username/password@server:port/services')
```

But the problem is my password contain @ character so it may become

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('username/p@ssword@server:port/services')
```

it return

> DatabaseError: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier
>   specified

I use Django with Oracle with this settings

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle', 
        'NAME': 'Services',  
        'USER': 'user',                      
        'PASSWORD': 'p@ssword',                  
        'HOST': 'ip',                      
        'PORT': 'port',                      
    }
}
```

I cant change password :( Does anyone know this problem?

Comment: Why is that a problem? What is the symptom?

Comment: DatabaseError: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Comment: @DanielRoseman the problem is `@` character in username's password, which is used in EasyConnect ([documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/oraclenetservices-neteasyconnect-133058.pdf))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I haven't tried cx_Oracle, but you might be able to connect by specifying the individual parameters -

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='username', password='p@ssword', dsn='server:port/services')
```

OR

```
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('server', 'port', 'services')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='username', password='p@ssword', dsn=dsn_tns)
```

Comment: Hey its work, But now it the hard part :( I use connection in Django DB. How can I force it to use that way of connection

Comment: My Django DB knowledge is next to nil :(. Sorry. You might want to create a new question specific for that?

Comment: Don't forget to use unicode (if still in Python 2.7?), like cx_Oracle.connect(user=**u'username'**, ...)...

Answer (score 4):

You can use any of the following way based on `Service Name` or `SID` whatever you have.

**With SID:**

```
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('server', 'port', 'sid')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='username', password='p@ssword', dsn=dsn_tns)
```

**OR**

**With Service Name:**

```
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('server', 'port', service_name='service_name')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='username', password='p@ssword', dsn=dsn_tns)
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('username/"p@ssword"@server:port/services')
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI: This **was** a long-standing [bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29199) in Django. The first stable version containing the fix is v2.1

Answer (score 1):

All the answers mentioned here did not work for SQLAlchemy.

Parsing the characters to create a valid URL worked:

```py
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
import urllib.parse

url_password = urllib.parse.quote_plus(password)
connection_string = f"oracle+cx_oracle://{username}:{url_password}@{server}:{port}/?service_name={service}"
connection = create_engine(connection_string)
```

Should probably do the same with the other components of the connection string.